# Soft keyboard hide part of editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, adjustpan

I have an activity:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ttm.reorderrv.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on the input field, everything below the cursor hides under the keyboard. If I click on the top line, the keyboard will hide everything except the top line. If I click on the bottom line, then all text will be visible. 
What can I do if I want the textView2 to be above the keyboard without resizing anything? 
I found many similar questions, and there is everywhere answer is "adjustSpan", but it's don't help me.

Comment: test all system flags once.. may be adjustResize or adjustNothing will work

Answer (score 0):

You can add ScrollView over your LinearLayout. This way you can scroll your layout while keyboard appears.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView2" />
    </LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>
```